# Mongoengine signals listens for all models

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine

I have setup `django` project with `mongoengine` for using mongodb with django. I have created 2 models and they work fine, but when I use signal listener for one model It also listens for another model, so how can I keep the signals bound to their models?

Here's my code for model User:

```py
from mongoengine import *
from mongoengine import signals
from datetime import datetime


class User(Document):
    uid = StringField(max_length=60, required=True)
    platform = StringField(max_length=20, required=True)
    index = StringField(max_length=80)
    last_updated = DateTimeField(required=True, default=datetime.now())

    meta = {
        'collection': 'social_users'
    }


def before_save(sender, document, **kwargs):
    if document.platform and document.uid:
        document.index = document.platform+'/'+document.uid

signals.pre_save.connect(before_save)
```

Here's another model `Error`

```py
from mongoengine import *
from datetime import datetime


class Error(Document):
    call = DictField(required=True)
    response = DictField(required=True)
    date = DateTimeField(default=datetime.now(), required=True)

    meta = {
        'collection': 'errors'
    }
```

Here's the file which I'm using to test the code:

```py
from src.social.models.error import Error
from src.social.models.user import User

error = Error.objects.first()

print(error.to_json())
```

But it doesn't work, throws the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Error' object has no attribute 'platform'
```

Please help me with this, thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured out a way to bind signals for particular models, here's the code how I did it:

```py
from mongoengine import *
from mongoengine import signals
from datetime import datetime


class User(Document):
    uid = StringField(max_length=60, required=True)
    platform = StringField(max_length=20, required=True)
    index = StringField(max_length=80)
    last_updated = DateTimeField(required=True, default=datetime.now())

    meta = {
        'collection': 'social_users'
    }

    @classmethod
    def pre_save(cls, sender, document, **kwargs):
        if document.platform and document.uid:
            document.index = document.platform+'/'+document.uid

signals.pre_save.connect(User.pre_save, sender=User)
```

Hope this helps the people who face the same problem.